# WebLogic, Unix, Java application to be deployed on Azure

Tags: unix, azure, weblogic

New to Azure. We are developing a product in Java, to be deployed on WebLogic and Unix platform. Can we deploy this application on Azure PaaS platform? Or please suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It is virtually impossible to deploy Weblogic Java application on Azure PaaS Platform. You should use Azure IaaS or JBoss AS on Azure PaaS.

To deploy weblogic Java application on Azure PaaS, you need to install weblogic into Azure PaaS and deploy java application with Jython script using "startup task("startup task" feature can install only silent installer and run *.bat script)".
I think this task is very very difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

A very generic question, but however based on the inputs I suggest you to go ahead with Azure Virtual Machines. This is the IaaS route, you have options to choose from CenOS, Ubuntu or Windows Server etc. as the base OS. On provisioning an Azure VM, it almost like you have the complete access to the server. You can install Weblogic or what ever the app server and deploy your application.

In terms of the PaaS route, the base platform in Windows Server 2008 R2 and you have liberty in just picking up the platform like either .net / java etc. Having a Weblogic over that is not possible.

IMHO, Weblogic on a PaaS means the PaaS provider must give the Weblogic platform directly and I guess the leading PaaS providers like Azure Cloud Services, Amazon ElasticBeanStalk, Google AppEngine, Heroku etc. don't give you that option of Weblogic. So IaaS fits your requirement.

However Weblogic being a product from Oracle, a quick google search returned me [Cloud Application Foundation](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/cloud-app-foundation/overview/index.html). There was a listing for Weblogic, the important thing with Oracle cloud is the manner of delivery of the cloud itself.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely tested app server on Azure is Tomcat. However, using AzureRunMe, you basically can deploy any Java program on Windows Azure. https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureRunMe You might want to touch base with two10degree to get their opinions as well. http://www.two10degrees.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle WebLogic is now fully supported in Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/campaigns/oracle/).